# Getting jar file with dependences from javaFX project

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, netbeans-7

I'm trying to build my jar file with dependences using this build.xml (NetBeans):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for --><!-- some examples of how to customize the build. --><!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) --><!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. --><project name="TargetAppDesktop" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project TargetAppDesktop.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. Those of them relevant for JavaFX project are: 

      -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
      -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
      -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
      -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
      -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -pre-jfx-jar:              called before FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -post-jfx-jar:             called after FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -pre-jfx-deploy:           called before FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -post-jfx-deploy:          called after FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

    (Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

    Example of inserting a HTML postprocessor after javaFX SDK deployment:

        <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
            <basename property="jfx.deployment.base" file="${jfx.deployment.jar}" suffix=".jar"/>
            <property name="jfx.deployment.html" location="${jfx.deployment.dir}${file.separator}${jfx.deployment.base}.html"/>
            <custompostprocess>
                <fileset dir="${jfx.deployment.html}"/>
            </custompostprocess>
        </target>

    Example of calling an Ant task from JavaFX SDK. Note that access to JavaFX SDK Ant tasks must be
    initialized; to ensure this is done add the dependence on -check-jfx-sdk-version target:

        <target name="-post-jfx-jar" depends="-check-jfx-sdk-version">
            <echo message="Calling jar task from JavaFX SDK"/>
            <fx:jar ...>
                ...
            </fx:jar>
        </target>

    For more details about JavaFX SDK Ant tasks go to
    http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

    For list of available properties check the files
    nbproject/build-impl.xml and nbproject/jfx-impl.xml.

    -->

<!--   Para  gerar um arquivo unico adicionar as linhas abaixo -->

    <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

        <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
             minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
             <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
        -->
        <property name="store.jar.name" value="TargetAppDesktop"/>


        <!-- don't edit below this line -->

        <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
            excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        </zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

    </target>


    <!--> Fim do codigo para arquivo unico -->
</project>
```

When I build it everything seems to be fine, but when I try to open my jar file I'm getting the error message from the javaFX launcher:

Unable to find application class name.

Somebody know what is happening? Or a easier way to get this jar?

Comment: Do you have a class, which extends Application?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213205

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the manifest a bit. From what you have:

```
<manifest>
     <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
</manifest>
```

To something similar to:

```
 <manifest>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
<!-- your javaFX version -->
              <attribute name="JavaFX-Version" value="2.2"/>
<!-- your main class -->
              <attribute name="JavaFX-Application-Class" value="package.MainClass"/>
<!-- your javaFx build path -->
              <attribute name="JavaFX-Class-Path" value="lib/Program.jar lib/Utils.jar lib/commons-codec-1.5
     .jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar lib/junit-4.10.j
     ar lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar lib/poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-201402
     08.jar lib/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.
     10-FINAL-20140208.jar lib/poi-scratchpad-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar lib/
     stax-api-1.0.1.jar lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
             <attribute name="Permissions" value="sandbox"/>

    </manifest>
```

I personally used the one above and it worked but as you can see it has things that were unique to my project. The easiest way to get your javaFX path and version would be to open the jar in the dist folder with 7zip or similar program and take a look at what is in the manifest for these fields.